# Are there any ways to set the `argparse.ArgumentParser()` to a string in the program in Python?

Tags: python, string, argparse

Are there any ways to set the `argparse.ArgumentParser()` to a string in the program in Python?

For example, I have a string `s = "A rocket in the sky --height 512 --width 512"` declared when running the program (instead of the user inputs in the command prompt), how can i get the values of height and width as int?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an explicit list of arguments to the [`ArgumentParser.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) method; just `.split()` your string and use that:

```
import argparse

s = "A rocket in the sky --height 512 --width 512"

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('--height')
p.add_argument('--width')
p.add_argument('everything_else', nargs='*')

args = p.parse_args(s.split())
print(args)
```

The above code will output:

```
Namespace(height='512', width='512', everything_else=['A', 'rocket', 'in', 'the', 'sky'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split()` to match `--height NNN` and build a custom list of arguments, which can then be passed to `parse_args`.

```py
import argparse
import re

def parse_args(s: str) -> argparse.Namespace:
    parts = re.split("(--\w+ \d+)", s)
    args = []
    for t in parts:
        if t.startswith("--"):
            args.extend(t.split())

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--height", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--width", type=int)
    return parser.parse_args(args)


namespace = parse_args("A rocket in the sky --height 512 --width 1234")
print(namespace)
```